# Storing a kernel matrix

Tags: kernel-trick, feature-engineering

I'm reading a [paper on feature hashing](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2206.pdf) and the authors state in the introduction that "limited memory makes storing a kernel matrix infeasible." I'm confused as to why the kernel matrix needs to be "stored." Given the inputs, isn't the kernel value typically computed on-the-fly? Are they saying that because the kernel function's value needs to be computed for each training point, and if the training dataset is very large, this makes the number of features for each testing point very large? How would this work in terms of prediction since the features of the testing set would depend on the training data?

Sorry if I sound confusing. I'm very new to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the paper you linked is mostly concerned about memory issues during calculation of the kernel matrix, rather than storing of the matrix itself. This is supported by the memory issues described, e.g., in
[Shi, Qinfeng, et al. "Hash kernels." International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics. 2009.](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/AISTATS09_ShiPDLSSV.pdf)

In fact, the whole thing may be a confusion of kernel matrix and [document-term-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix), or something similar to that.

---

Regarding kernel matrix storage:

Whether or not a kernel matrix needs to be stored (in the sense of: it is needed for prediction of test points) will depend on the employed method.

A Support Vector Machine may only require to store the training points $\mathbf{x}_i$ and parameters $\alpha_i$, $b$, since the predictor is typically written as:

$$ f_{svm}(\mathbf{x'}) = \sum \alpha_i y_i k(\mathbf{x_i},\mathbf{x'}) +b$$

where $k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x'})$ is the kernel function.
Actually, only the support vectors have to be stored, i.e., all 
$\mathbf{x}_i$ with $\alpha_i \neq 0$.

On the other hand, methods like Gaussian Process Regression (Kriging) usually require the whole kernel (or covariance) matrix, or rather its inverse, see:

$$ f_{gpr}(\mathbf{x'}) = \hat{\mu} + \psi^T \Psi^{-1} (\mathbf{y-\mathbf{1}} \hat{\mu}),$$

where $\hat{\mu}$ is a parameter of the model, $\mathbf{y}$ is the vector of all training observations $y_i$, $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of ones (same length as $\mathbf{y}$), $\psi$ is the vector containing  $k(\mathbf{x_i},\mathbf{x'})$,
and $\Psi$ is the kernel matrix containing all $k(\mathbf{x_i},\mathbf{x_j})$.